# Someone explain why this isn't filling in the square

Tags: javascript, libpng

It's just making a red line along the top and left edge and I don't understand why.  Shouldn't the nested for loops iterate through every possible x,y coordinate?

```
function createSquare() {
    var height = 50;
    var width = 50;
    var img = new PNGlib(width, height, 256);
    var background = img.color(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (var x = 0; x <= width; x ++) {
        for (var y = 0; y <= height; y ++) {
            img.buffer[img.index(x, y)] = img.color(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
        }
    }

    return ('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + img.getBase64() + '">');
}
```

Comment: Why `<=` instead of just `<` is used in for condition?

Comment: oh... why the comment instead of the answer?  :D

Comment: So what is the output @ScottBeeson?

Comment: Not sure why it didn't hit me that it still increments after it meets the condition, so < is what I wanted, and it fixed the problem.  Please post as answer so I can credit you @raina77ow

Comment: Never mind, it's one of the most common types of bugs I've seen in codebase I worked with. That's why I usually fix these almost automatically - and write some big comment explaining why `<=` is used in some particular case, if that turns out to be not a bug. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used PNGLib (would be interesting to try, though), but from my experience `<=` used in `for` loop exit condition is almost always an error. )

Comment: Good catch.  I'm admittedly curious as to why this produced that behavior though.